# Sharing multiple images on facebook post

Tags: android, facebook, image, file-upload

I want to share multiple images along with the status on the Facebook, but i am not able to post all of them. I am creating an array-list of the images from the sdcard and converting each one to the byte object. Below is the code for the upload. Can anyone please let me know where i am lacking in the code or any better way to implement the requirement.

Below is the code written on the share button click:

```
public void loginToFacebook() {

        String hashKey = showHashKey(MainActivity.this);
        Log.d("hashKey", ">>> " + hashKey);

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

            if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                Session session = facebook.getSession();
                postToWall();
            }
            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }
        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                            Log.e("Face onCancel", "-> ok");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                            postToWall();
                            // Making show access tokens button visible
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            Log.e("Face onError", "-> " + error);
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors
                            Log.e("Face onFacebookError", "-> " + fberror);

                        }

                    });
        }
    }



 public String showHashKey(Context context) {
        String hashkey = "";
        try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.example.demofacebook", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); // Your
            // package
            // name
            // here
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                // Log.v("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                // Base64.DEFAULT));
                hashkey = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return hashkey;
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null) {
            if (facebook.getSession() != null) {
                Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
                Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(MainActivity.this,
                        requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
        // Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
        // resultCode, data);
        // Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
        // resultCode, data);

        // publishFeedDialog();
    }

    public void postToWall() {
        publishStory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Save current session
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // Check if Session is Opened or not, if open & clicked on share
            // button publish the story
            if (session != null && state.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("FbShare", "Session is opened");
                if (session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
                    Log.d("FbShare", "Starting share");
                    publishAction();
                } else {
                    Log.d("FbShare", "Session dont have permissions");
                    publishStory();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("FbShare", "Invalid fb Session");
            }
        }
    }

    private void publishStory() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.getState().isOpened()) {
            checkSessionAndPost();
        } else {
            Log.d("FbShare", "Session is null");
            // session = new Session(ShareActivity.this);
            session = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(APP_ID)
                    .build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.addCallback(statusCallback);

            Log.d("FbShare", "Session info - " + session);
            try {
                Log.d("FbShare", "Opening session for read");
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(MainActivity.this));
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("FbShare", "Exception Caught");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Unable to post your score on facebook",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkSessionAndPost() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        session.addCallback(statusCallback);
        Log.d("FbShare",
                "Session Permissions Are - " + session.getPermissions());
        if (session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
            publishAction();
        } else {
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    MainActivity.this, permissions));
        }
    }
// filePaths is arraylist of the images from sdcard
    private void publishAction() {
        final Bundle params = new Bundle();
        FileInputStream stream = null;
        byte[] imgData = null;
        try {
            params.putString("name", "Hello Wednesday test 20 Nov");
            params.putString("caption", "test 20 Nov");
            params.putString("link", "");
            String[] byteStrings = new String[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++) {
                Log.i("PASSED FILE", "==== " + filePaths.get(i));
                Log.i("PICTURE FILE", "==== " + "picture" + (i + 1));
                stream = new FileInputStream(filePaths.get(i));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                imgData = bos.toByteArray();
                byteStrings[i] = filePaths.get(i).toString();
                params.putByteArray("picture" + i + 1, imgData);
            }
            // params.putStringArray("images" , byteStrings);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // params.putString(
        // "description",
        // "");

        // params.putString("picture", ""+imgData);
        // params.putByteArray("picture2", imgData);
        // params.putByteArray("picture3", imgData);
        // params.putStringArrayList("picture", filePaths);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final String response = facebook.request("me/photos",
                            params, "POST");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Post uploaded successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Utility.dismissCustomProgressDialog();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Utility.dismissCustomProgressDialog();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Utility.dismissCustomProgressDialog();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Utility.dismissCustomProgressDialog();
                }
            }
        }) {
        }.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the use of Session (which was introduced in v3.0 of the SDK) and Facebook (which is now deprecated), both of which manage your access token and help you make requests. This makes your logic very difficult to decipher. Please stick to ONLY Session, and remove all use of deprecated code (everything in the Facebook class).

Secondly, there's a helper method that helps you upload photos, it's in the Request class: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newUploadPhotoRequest(Session,%20Bitmap,%20Callback). It's also overloaded to take either a Bitmap or a File.

If you want to upload multiple photos, you can create multiple requests, and add them to a batch, like:

```
Request r1 = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(...);
Request r2 = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(...);
RequestBatch batch = new RequestBatch(r1, r2);
batch.executeAsync();
```

Lastly, the me/photos endpoint only accepts the "source" (the image), "message", and "place" parameters, and does not accept "caption" or "link". See the detailed documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos