# Share Multiple Images on Facebook using Facebook sdk 4.2.2

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am using Facebook SDK version 4.2.2.

I am able to `share single image` from my app on **Facebook**. But i don't have any reference to share `multiple images` on **Facebook** through my app.

I followed up all the steps mentioned in the official site of Facebook SDK  i.e. https://developers.facebook.com/

Could you please help me out.

Comment: Pretty sure it is not possible

Comment: Okay, it means we cant share share multiple image on facebook. Only single image we can share :(

Comment: @MamtaKaundal check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089729/sharing-multiple-images-on-facebook-post